# How to copy text, in a cell, which includes a hyperlink?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make sure that

```
Sheets("Add").Cells(x, 2) = Sheets("Scan").Range("A11")
```

This works, however `Sheets("Add").Cells(x, 2)` will have a hyperlink in the text.

Is there a way to edit the code such that it will copy the text as well as the hyperlink from `Sheets("Add").Cells(x, 2) to Sheets("Scan").Range("A11")`

```vb
Sub scan()
    Dim erow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim x As Integer

    lastRow = Sheets("Scan").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    count = 0
    For x = 2 To lastRow
        If Sheets("Add").Cells(x, 1) = Sheets("Scan").Range("B3") Then
            Sheets("Scan").Range("A11") = Sheets("Add").Cells(x, 2)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to memory conflict, I don't like to use `Copy` method.

Please try replace

```vb
Sheets("Scan").Range("A11") = Sheets("Add").Cells(x, 2)
```

with

```vb
Dim sSubAddress As String, sScreenTip As String, sTextToDisplay As String, sAddress As String

With Sheets("Add").Cells(x, 2).Hyperlinks(1)
    sAddress = .Address
    sSubAddress = .SubAddress
    sScreenTip = .ScreenTip
    sTextToDisplay = .TextToDisplay
    With Sheets("Scan").Hyperlinks.Add(anchor:=Sheets("Scan").Range("A11"), Address:="")
        If sAddress <> "" Then .Address = sAddress
        If sTextToDisplay <> "" Then .TextToDisplay = sTextToDisplay
        If sSubAddress <> "" Then .SubAddress = sSubAddress
        If sScreenTip <> "" Then .ScreenTip = sScreenTip
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few methods. The easiest would be to copy the whole cell:

```
Sheets("Add").Cells(x, 2).copy Sheets("Scan").Range("A11")
```

Note That the **"copy"** method is a method of the **source** range, and **destination** is the **parameter** of the method.

Comment: Hi! How can I add that to my code? Now my Sheets("Scan").Range("A11") shows true...

Comment: Just put it in place of 
  
"Sheets("Scan").Range("A11") = Sheets("Add").Cells(x, 2)" line